# Tutorial MVC ASP.NET - Localización del Precio

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-5, localización

En el tutorial sobre cómo hacer aplicaciones MVC en .NET5 y con el framework ASP.NET en el siguiente [enlace](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/start-mvc?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio), existe un campo `Price` de tipo Currency.
Estoy ejecutando el programa en un entorno es-ES Windows 10.
El _layout está conla etiqueta `<html lang="es-es">`.
El Modelo tiene el campo Price descrito así:

```
     [Range(1.00, 100.00)]
        [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
        [Column(TypeName = "decimal(18, 2)")]
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
```

Pero cuando intento Editar y/o Crear un nuevo Movie, el precio se muestra correctamente con coma en es-ES `9,99`, pero cuando lo edito no me admite la coma, y obtengo el error **The field Price must be a number**, y si pongo un punto `9.9`, lo ignora y resulta `99`.

¿De qué manera se puede hacer que acepte la coma?